# how do i call javascript fuction in my php wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want the js to be executed here

```
add_shortcode('mountaintop_form_start', 'mountaintop_form_shortcode_start');

// Process form submission for start form
function process_mountaintop_form_start() {
    global $hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port;

    // Check if the form is submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'process_mountaintop_form_start') {
        // Get form data
        $medarbejder_nummer = isset($_POST['medarbejder_nummer']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['medarbejder_nummer']) : '';
        $enhed             = isset($_POST['enhed']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enhed']) : '';

        // Get current date and time
        $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // Connect to MySQL server
        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);

        // Check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        // Insert data into the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (medarbejder_nummer, enhed, datecreated) VALUES ('$medarbejder_nummer', '$enhed', '$current_date')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            // Data inserted successfully
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
    //I want JS Code here
}
```

[My filemanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMYVi.png)

the js I want to execute

```
function showPopup() {
   alert("Dataen er blevet indsendt!");
}

showPopup();
window.location.href = 'example link';
```

I tried this but maybe I f*** up the pathing or something else

```
function enqueue_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__), array(), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script');
```

Comment: when you want to execute after insert?

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortcode. This is what you are looking

```
add_shortcode('mountaintop_form_start', 'mountaintop_form_shortcode_start');

// Process form submission for start form
function process_mountaintop_form_start() {
    global $hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port;

    // Check if the form is submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'process_mountaintop_form_start') {
        // Get form data
        $medarbejder_nummer = isset($_POST['medarbejder_nummer']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['medarbejder_nummer']) : '';
        $enhed             = isset($_POST['enhed']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enhed']) : '';

        // Get current date and time
        $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // Connect to MySQL server
        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);

        // Check connection
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        // Insert data into the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (medarbejder_nummer, enhed, datecreated) VALUES ('$medarbejder_nummer', '$enhed', '$current_date')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            // Data inserted successfully
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
    //I want JS Code here
    echo "<script>function showPopup() {
           alert('Dataen er blevet indsendt!');
        }

        showPopup();
        window.location.href = 'example link';</script>";
}
```